# Looking for a short story about a man who freezes his brain and awakens inside a computer

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

Does anyone remember reading this story?  He dies, his brain is frozen, and he awakens to find he's far in the future, and future humans have put his brain into a computer, and he's excited at first, but they start doing experiments on him and won't let him die.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds a bit like ["Permutation City"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_City) by Greg Egan, except

> the person performing the experiments and preventing the protagonist's suicide is his real world self.

Comment: The character doesn't wake up "far in the future" in that story either, nor had he died before they created the simulation of his brain (they had some non-destructive way of scanning brains), so I doubt that's the one.

Comment: There are differences, agreed, but part two of the book *is* set in the far future.  People don't always remember every detail of a book correctly. There seemed like enough similarity here that it might be the one @RichardG was looking for.

Comment: I agree people don't remember every detail, but speaking of that, I don't remember part 2 as set in the far future--my memory was that it was set inside a simulated universe with different "laws of physics" than ours (based on some kind of 3D [cellular automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton) type rules) that somehow, via the metaphysical ideas about [Dust Theory](http://gregegan.customer.netspace.net.au/PERMUTATION/FAQ/FAQ.html), had become an independently-running universe of its own, so it was no longer possible for those inside to return to our universe.

Comment: That sounds really close, @Christi.  I haven't read that book but it looks good.  I'm fairly certain it was a short story, though.  Maybe I just dreamed it... :-)

Comment: Richard, Permutation City was expanded from a 1992 short story called "Dust" where the main character kept scanning his brain to make uploads but they kept killing themselves, then one woke up to find the kill switch had been disabled. That story was reprinted in this collection: http://www.amazon.com/The-Years-Best-Science-Fiction/dp/0312094248

Comment: @Hypnosifl -- The citizens in the new universe wait several thousand subjective years before activating the copy they have of the main character.